# How to profile a web crawler?

Tags: profiling, web-crawler

I have a 2 slightly different versions of a web-crawler. I want to compare them in performance (spesifically time taken to crawl a given domain). I have considered these two options:

1. Run them one at a time, compare time taken.
2. Run both of them at the same time, compare time taken.

The drawback of 1 is, network can be slower/faster when running second one. The drawback of 2 is, one can hijack most of the bandwidth and seems to be working faster, while other could work better given the same bandwidth.

I don't know how to (if possible) limit bandwidth (and cpu usage maybe?) per process. If I could do that, I would give each a fair share and run them at the same time, so it could work.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Select Option 1 and take a lot of samples.  Run one for a week, then run the other for a week.  The network bandwidth will of course vary, but should average out.

On another note, you'll probably want to find a way to throttle your crawler so it doesn't consume all your resources.  Once you have that, option 2 becomes a better choice.